# Generate SHA 1 key in xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps

How to generate SHA 1 key from Xcode for Google Maps? I search in google but could not able to find the solution. Like In Android Studio i can easily get the SHA 1 key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For iOS you don't need to generate SHA key for google map,

You can restrict your app by simply adding your app Bundle Identifier.**

[image]